# Deducing the base type from a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Visual Studio 2017, C++ with C++17

Is there any way to use a template parameter and deduce the base type?

Example: If the template parameter is `std::string` I want to declare a `char` inside the function.
If the template parameter is `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` I want to declare an `unsigned char` inside the function:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef basic_string<uchar> ustring;

template <typename str>
void exampleFunc(vector<str> &vec)
{
    // Pseudo-code to be evaluated at ***compile time***
    if (typeof(str) == ustring)
        uchar c;
    if (typeof(str) == string)
        char c;

    // ... code ...
}
int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    vector<ustring> uvec;

    exampleFunc(vec);
    exampleFunc(uvec);
}
```

Comment: In the specific case of `basic_string`, that's just `typename str::CharT`.

Comment: Using `typeof` or `typeid` or other such techniques to select between functionality is often a sign of bad design. Can't you use overloading or template specialization instead? Or as mentioned, the `CharT` type of the string itself?

Comment: its not the "base" type, but a template parameter. And `std::unsigned string` is `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` ?

Comment: @Quentin: `value_type` not `CharT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want `std::basic_string` parameterised by different character types, say so:

```
template <typename Chr>
void exampleFunc(std::vector<std::basic_string<Chr>> &vec) ...
```

Comment: That worked to declare a char/uchar. What if I also need to declare a string/ustring?

Comment: @Johnny declare `std::basic_string<Chr>`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you write it like:

```
template <typename str>
void exampleFunc(std::vector<str> &vec)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_base_of<str, std::string>::value)
  {
    char c;
    // ...
  }
  else
  {
    // ...
  }
  // ... code ...
}
```